# Try/catch block shows TypeError: until_not() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import autoit
wait = WebDriverWait
firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
firefox_options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=firefox_options, executable_path=r'C:\\firefoxdriver\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input').send_keys('mngr253724')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input').send_keys('Et54Uje')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)

try:
    page_loaded = wait.until_not(
        lambda driver: driver.current_url == "http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php"
    )
except TimeoutException:
    driver.fail("Loading timeout expired")

driver.assertEqual(
    driver.current_url,
    correct_page,
    msg="Successful Login"
)
```

Error:

```
File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/Test_Order/Test_Order.py", line 27, in <module>
lambda driver: driver.current_url == "http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php"
TypeError: until_not() missing 1 required positional argument: 'method'
```

Comment: until_not method expects a required parameter, you need to fix that. There is no problem with your try...except

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate `WebDriverWait`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 5)
```

And you can use `wait` object.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
try:
    page_loaded = wait.until_not(
        lambda driver: driver.current_url == "http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php"
    )
except TimeoutException:
    driver.fail("Loading timeout expired")
```

with:

```
try:
    page_loaded = wait.until_not(EC.url_to_be("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php"))
except TimeoutException:
    driver.fail("Loading timeout expired")
```

***Note:*** you have to do some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

***PS:*** and you have to correctly define your `wait`:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10)
```

More information can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trials I am still not sure about your usecase and the reason why you want to use the *until* condition as `until_not` as in:

```
page_loaded = wait.until_not(lambda driver: driver.current_url == "http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php")
```

Incase your usecase is to validate whether on effective/wrong credentials the application takes the user to the page with *url* as `http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/manager/Managerhomepage.php` or not, you can use the following solution:

- To validate the successful/unsuccessful login, you can either check for the new *URL* to contain **Managerhomepage** or the new *Page Title* to contain **Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage**. Hence you can use *WebDriverWait* with *expected-conditions* set either as `url_contains()` or `title_contains()` as follows:
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
  from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input').send_keys('mngr144003')
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input').send_keys('bUtymYr')
  driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input[1]').click()
  try:
              WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_contains("Managerhomepage"))
          #WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Manager"))
          print("Login is successful. Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
  except (TimeoutException,UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
          print("Loading timeout expired")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output(successful login):

  ```
  Login is successful. Page Title is : Guru99 Bank Manager HomePage
  ```
- Console Output(unsuccessful login):

  ```
  Loading timeout expired
  ```